# The Chow ring of affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, intersection-theory

I want to show that $\operatorname{CH}(\mathbb{A}^n) = \mathbb{Z}$ from first principles. There's a proof of this in 3264 by Eisenbud and Harris that utilizes the definition of rational equivalence given by differences of cycles on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^n$; I would like to show this using the divisors on subvarieties formulation.

The key part of the proof is to show that any proper subvariety $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ is rationally equivalent to zero. The idea I have is to find a subvariety $Z$ such that $Y \subset Z \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and $Z$ is one dimension larger than $Y$; then $Y$ is a divisor on $Z$ since it is cut out by equations, and therefore rationally equivalent to zero. Does this work? How can I show rigorously that we can always find such a $Z$?

Comment: In general, finding a $Z$ where $Y$ is rationally equivalent to zero is hopeless, since any general choice of $Z$ will have complicated Chow groups.

Comment: @Mohan I think I don't understand your point. I don't want to regard $Y$ as an element of $\operatorname{CH}(Z)$, but find a $Z$ such that $Y$ is a divisor on $Z$, all within  $\operatorname{CH}(\mathbb{A}^n)$ since rational equivalences are generated by all divisors on all subvarieties.

Comment: How does it follow that merely because $Y\subset Z$ is a divisor (not necessarily a principal divisor, of course) that it's class is zero in chow group of the affine space?

Comment: @Mohan I meant to write principal divisor, since the fact that $Y$ is rationally equivalent to zero means that it is in fact a principal divisor on some such $Z$. My guess was that it would follow from the fact that $Y$ is cut out by equations.

Comment: I think you are using the phrase cut out by equations loosely. Every subvariety of any variety is cut out by equations, but chow groups can be pretty complicated.

Comment: @Mohan that's certainly possible but such an argument definitely works in codimension $1$. We let $Y$ be the vanishing of a single equation $f$ and can immediately conclude that $\operatorname{CH}_{n-1}(\mathbb{A}^n) = 0$. The problem is higher codimension, it probably does not suffice to take a codimension $k$ subvariety and just multiply it by a copy of $\mathbb{A}^1$, but I don't see another obvious way to go up a dimension.

Comment: You also get $CH_0(\mathbb A^n)=0$ for free: if $P\in \mathbb A^n$ just choose a line $L$ through $P$ and a regular affine function  $f\in \mathcal O(L)$ vanishing at $P$. Then $\operatorname {div}(f)=P$ and so $CH_0(\mathbb A^n)=0$. This and your previous comment conspire to give a completely elementary computation of $CH(\mathbb A^2)$ ! (Good question by the way: +1)

Comment: Also: the determination of the Chow groups of affine space is a trivial consequence of Fulton's Propostion 1.9 in his famous book *Intersection Theory*. His proof is in the spirit you like and I would not be surprised if you could  extract an elementary proof in the very special case you are interested in. (He studies affine bundles over an arbitrary base, which in your case would just be a point!)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thank you, I will take a look!

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg In deducing $CH_0(\mathbb{A}^n_k)=0$, I think if $k$ is not algebraic closed, then we can't find a *line* through a given closed point $P$ in general. We only know the residue field of $P$ is a finite extension of $k$. Is there still a way to see that $P$ is given by a divisor associated to a regular function on a dimension 1 subvariety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof follows from the suggestion of Georges Elencwajg that I study [the Bible](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387985497).

**Proposition:** Let $X$ be a scheme, and $\pi:E \rightarrow X$ a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ on $X$. Then for all $k \geq 0$, the pull back homomorphism $\pi^\ast :\operatorname{CH}_k(X) \rightarrow \operatorname{CH}_{k+r}(E)$ is surjective.

**Proof:** Note that $\pi^\ast$ maps $\operatorname{CH}_k(X)$ to $\operatorname{CH}_{k+r}(E)$ since a cycle will gain a factor of $\mathbb{A}^r$ under preimage. We proceed via induction on $\dim X$; let $U$ be an open affine on which $E$ is trivial, e.g, such that $E|_U \cong U \times \mathbb{A}^r$, and set $Y = U^c$. By excision, we have the following diagram:

[image: Morphism of excision sequences]
    By the four lemma, if we can show that $\operatorname{CH}_k(Y) \rightarrow \operatorname{CH}_{k+r}(E|_Y)$ and $\operatorname{CH}_k(U) \rightarrow \operatorname{CH}_K(U \times \mathbb{A}^r)$ are surjections, it follows that $\pi^\ast$ is a surjection, and the former map is a surjection by the inductive hypothesis. Therefore, we need only show that the rightmost arrow factors, e.g, we have reduced the proof the assertion to the case of $X = \operatorname{Spec} R$ affine, and $E = X \times \mathbb{A}^r$ is the trivial bundle (by choice of $U$ above). Moreover, we can factor $\pi$ as a series of projections: $$\pi:E = X \times \mathbb{A}^r \rightarrow X \times \mathbb{A}^{r-1} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow X \times \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow X$$ Therefore, we may assume that $r=1$ by treating each locally free sheaf in the chain as a rank $1$ free sheaf on the scheme below, and we have that $$E= X \times \mathbb{A}^1 = \operatorname{Spec} R \otimes_k \operatorname{Spec} k[t] = \operatorname{Spec} R[t]$$

We are then tasked with showing that $\pi^\ast: \operatorname{CH}_k(X) \rightarrow \operatorname{CH}_{k+1}(X \times \mathbb{A}^1)$ is surjective; to that end, let $V \subset X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ be a $(k+1)$-dimensional subvariety, and let $W = \overline{\pi(V)}$. If $\dim W = k$, then $V = W \times \mathbb{A}^1$ since $\pi$ is a projection, so $[V] = \pi^\ast[W]$. If $\dim W = k+1$ (this is the only other option) we must show that $[V]$ is in the image of the induced pullback map $\operatorname{CH}_k(W) \rightarrow \operatorname{CH}_{k+1}(W \times \mathbb{A}^1)$. We can therefore assume that $W = X$, let $I(V)$ be the vanishing ideal of $V$, and consider the related ideal $$I(V) \otimes_R K \subset K[t]$$ where $K$ is the fraction field of $R$. This ideal is not the unit ideal, as otherwise $V= W \times \mathbb{A}^1$ which we handled above. Since $K[t]$ is a PID, $I(V) \otimes_R K[t] = (\varphi)$ for some $\varphi \in K[t]$. Then the divisor of $\varphi$ (taken as a function on $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$) is $[V]$ by construction, up to terms of the form $\pi^\ast [W_i]$ for $W_i \subset X$ corresponding to tensoring with $K$, from which the result follows. $\blacksquare$

This result gives an easy alternative derivation of the Chow ring of affine space by showing that all subvarieties are rationally equivalent to zero. First, we have that $\operatorname{CH}_0(\mathbb{A}^n) =0$ for all $n$; to see this, for any $x \in \mathbb{A}^n$, pick a line $L \cong \mathbb{A}^1 \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ through $x$ and a function on $L$ vanishing (only) on $x$. Then, by the above result, $\operatorname{CH}_0(\mathbb{A}^{n-k}) \rightarrow \operatorname{CH}_k(\mathbb{A}^n)$ is surjective for all $k< n$, from which the result follows.