Exercise 12.5.3 in David Cox "Toric Varieties"
I have a question regarding the following Exercise 12.5.3. in Cox "Toric Variety" book:
Show directly from the definitions that Chow groups of affine space are:
$$ A_{k}(\mathbb{C}^{p}) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{C}^{p}] & \text{if } k = p, \\
0 & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}    $$
Eisenbud and Harris prove it in "3264 and All That; Intersection Theory in Algebraic Geometry", however they use the alternative definition of Rational equivalence that is, two cycles are rationally equivalent if there is a rationally parametrized family of cycles interpolating between them. However in Cox the rational equivalence is defined via the notions of [div(f)],  that is a $k$-cycle is rationally equivalent to zero if there are finitely many $k+1$-dimensional irreducible subvarieties $W_{i}\subseteq X$ and nonzero rational functions $f_{i}\in \mathbb{C}(W_{i})$ such that $\alpha = \sum_{i}[div_{W_{i}}(f_{i})]$. Cox wants us to directly use the definition to prove this, there is not a lot of issue for proving $k=p$ part, as the top dimension of $n$-dimensional irreducible variety should a free abelian group generated by irreducible components of dimension $n$ (This can be seen by the definition). However why all the other cases are zero?
In the case of $p=2$ the points can be divisors over a line that is passing them, and line are equivalent to zero as the coordinate ring is UFD (By Hartshorne or Cox for instance), So it seems in general case we have to somehow show any irreducible subvariety of dimension $k$ can be sum of divisors over $k+1$ dimensional subvarieties but I'm not sure how to do that? is there any result that makes this simpler for the complex varieties as for general affine variety seems to be complicated?
Many Thanks. :)
P.S. There is also a response in  The Chow ring of affine space. However, it seems that you need more advance machinery that is not discussed in Cox's book.

Have you looked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662140/the-chow-ring-of-affine-space?rq=1 and Georges' comments therein?

Hey KReiser Thank you for your response. Yes I have seen this post, but as this needs the notion of flat pull-back of cycles and in Toric variety by Cox it does not introduce such notions, so it seems at least in the case of $\mathbb{C}^{p}$ it follows purely by definition, I was wondering if there is some simple argument that makes it work in this case rather than using the proposition proved in this post?

I mentioned Georges' comments because he explicitly calls out Fulton's proof as a potential inspiration for an elementary proof - I do recognize that the listed answer doesn't quite match what you're asking for.

I see, I completely agree, this could be a great place to start looking into such elementary proof. Thank you so much.
